# cannot allocate memory service systemd-networkd

Tags: linux, systemd-networkd

I encountered an issue with `systemd-networkd` where it failed to start the device monitor and could not create the manager due to a "Cannot allocate memory" error.

I have tried restarting `systemd-networkd` using the command `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`, but the logs did not provide any helpful information.

It's worth noting that I have checked the available memory using the `free -h` command, and it shows that I have 13Gi of available memory.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on understanding this error and resolving the issue. Additionally, if there are any specific troubleshooting steps or configurations that I should check, please let me know.

Comment: May you please provide the full error message?

Comment: Which distribution? Are you sure the error is caused by networkd, and not by a dependent deamon (which delay networkd). When you restart it, do it fail again? (I do not fully understand your second paragraph). How to debug: minimal configuration, and then add files, until you see the file which cause the error (maybe a syntax error which causes an infinite loop);

Comment: this is the error that i got : 

systemd-networkd]: Failed to start device monitor: Cannot allocate memory
systemd-networkd: Could not create manager: Cannot allocate memory

Comment: @paladin thats the error output

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi when i restart the service, it fail again yup

Comment: I assume some syntax error, which is allocating too much memory. Try to disable most of them, and enable one at a time. Then try to comments most lines on the file which cause failure, until you find the relevant line.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi the syntax inside my netplan config file ? with contain the routes config ?

Comment: I do not know. It is called debugging. Start without making ANY assumption. We can start with just an assumption: most people get networkd working (with initial difficulties), so try to assume the error in somewhere on your side (configuration, missing packages, etc.). Only later you may assume it is a networkd bug (you will encounter them).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it seems that the config is configured correctly ! i don't know whats going on tbh

Comment: Copy and remove all configuration of networkd. Then add one file at a time and test. There is no other way (or better: the other way takes much longer: it is about reading all configuration and checking that you are using syntax as expected, for the version you are using, etc... and you will miss some cases, so it will take weeks). So please: stop random look, and do incremental changes until the problem appear. Do not waste your time and time of other people.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi should i look to the file that exist inside /etc/netplan ? there is only one file there ! that contain the routes 
im using ubuntu anyway

Comment: When you "generate" or "apply", netplan (AFAIK) will create the files which are used by networkd (if you configured netplan to use networkd, and you are using networkd, so you disabled any other network manager). Then you have the systemd-networkd file to test. And it should give you an hints where the problem is.

Comment: the problem is that i can't delete files or something ! because im working inside a client servers ! i can get out from the server if i made any bad config you know.
also if i make netplan apply it said that i need to repair the systemd-networkd first, and the /etc/systemd/network the directory of systemd-networkd service is empty